# How to have the designer serialize a collection of objects in WinForms?

Tags: c#, winforms, serialization, windows-forms-designer

I have a class:

```
public class Filter
{
    public Filter (string name, string value)
    {
        Name = name;
        Value = value;
    }

    public string Name {get; private set;}
    public string Value {get; set;}
}
```

And a collection class:

```
public class FilterCollection : Collection<Filter>
{
   // code elided
}
```

My component class:

```
public class MyComponent : Component
{
    // ...

    [Editor(typeof(FilterEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
    public FilterCollection Filters { get; set; }

    // ...
}
```

The problem is that the collection is not serialized *correctly* by the designer.

I'm sure I'm missing something but I don't know what.

### ADDITIONAL INFO

What I would like the designer.cs file to have is something along the following:

```
myComponent.Filters.Add (new Filter ("some name", "some value"));
myComponent.Filters.Add (new Filter ("other name", "other value"));
```

Is this feasible?

Comment: Do you have a serialization provider? I haven't done any designer serialization before (maybe I'll take this opportunity to learn more about it) - but according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171834.aspx it appears you need a serialization provider and serializer(s) for the provider to use.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5736034/c-sharp-component-collection-property-not-serialized-when-filled-from-property-s) will help you

Comment: The **Additional Info** should be a different question. It appears to be unrelated to the current issue.

Comment: Not really, it is related but I must agree with you that my question needs to be updated to relate to that fact. I will do that now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, problem solved.

I needed to use a *TypeConverter* for my *Filter* class:

```
internal class FilterConverter : TypeConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvertTo (ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type destinationType)
    {
        return destinationType == typeof(InstanceDescriptor) || base.CanConvertTo (context, destinationType);
    }

    public override object ConvertTo (ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
    {
        if (destinationType == typeof(InstanceDescriptor) && value is Filter)
        {
            ConstructorInfo constructor = typeof (Filter).GetConstructor (new[] {typeof (string), typeof (string)});

            var filter = value as Filter;
            var descriptor = new InstanceDescriptor (constructor, new[] {filter.Name, filter.Value}, true);

            return descriptor;
        }
        return base.ConvertTo (context, culture, value, destinationType);
    }
}
```

The converter is then added to the *Filter* class like so:

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(FilterConverter))]
public class Filter
{
    // ...
}
```

The important thing to note here is the creation of an instance descriptor with the required parameters for the *Filter* constructor. Also, you need to set the last parameter (*isComplete*) of the *InstanceDescriptor* constructor to **true**.